# Location Manager remove updates permission

Tags: android, android-location

I am using android studio and compileSdkVersion  is 23
in that i am using below code

```
 if(locationManager != null){
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSListener.this);
        }
```

to stop gps update where GPS Listener is a class which implements LocationListener.

but in removeUpdates line i am getting below lint warning

> Call requires permission which may be rejected by user: code should
>   explicitly check to see if permission is available (with
>   `checkPermission`) or handle a potential `SecurityException`

I am not getting what is the issue in the above code.
Any extra permission need to be added in manifest file?.

Regards.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/preview/features/runtime-permissions.html

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Since SDK 23, you should/need to check the permission before you call Location API functionality. Here is an example of how to do it:

```
if (locationManager != null) {
    if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            || checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSListener.this);
    }
}
```

There is `checkSelfPermission()`, which is to check if 'you' (this app) has the correct permissions. There is also `checkPermission()`, which is to check if another process has the correct permissions.

**Notes**

- next to doing this runtime check, it is still also necessary to require the relevant permissions in the AndroidManifest.
- if your targetSdk is < 23, you should use `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission()` instead (thanks to JerryBrady)

Comment: Note that if your target is < 23, you should use ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission() instead.

Comment: I want to  cry. Why would the app need a permission to remove an already attached locationlistener from the location manager?

Answer (score 14):

I wasn't able to use `checkSelfPermission()`, because my min API is 14 and 23 is required. Knowing that, you can also `try` to `catch` a `SecurityException`.

Example:

```
try {
    locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSListener.this);
} catch (SecurityException e) {
    Log.e("PERMISSION_EXCEPTION","PERMISSION_NOT_GRANTED");
}
```

Comment: Question is for the target sdk version 23. There is no relation with min api.

Comment: Question was for "compileSdkVersion 23" which does not mean the app is targeting 23.

If you want backward compatibility with full Android M support, use ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission() instead and it will work.

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't realize that. But I think that this option using try - catch still useful.

Comment: This answer is helped me. But I think this was not a proper solution. But I upvoted it.

Answer (score 5):

To add to Jerry Brady's comment regarding ContextCompat, this is be the full code for < 23:

```
 if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is my solution !

```
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {

                if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                        || checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    lm.removeUpdates(this);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                lm.removeUpdates(this);

            }
```