# Permission is not recognized by Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

iam using Android Studio 2.1 and Android SDK 5.
Android Studio is not recognizing the permission for CALL_PHONE.
How to resolve this problem?
In pictures you can see how i did it.

[image: android manifest file]

[image]

Comment: It's not that it's not recognizing that manifest permission. It's just telling you that you need to check in your code that it has been granted, due to Marshmallow's new permissions model. Like here, with a location permission: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32715189/location-manager-remove-updates-permission

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your manifest file is fine. Problem is with user denying permission for Call after application is installed.

You need to check for permission at runtime as

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)
    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
   // your code here
}
```